# Glscene Ugly Texture with Materiallib

Tags: textures, glscene

I am using GLScene in my delphi project. I add some freeform on my scene (for example tooth). in the past I don't use material libs. I add my texture via the material property directrly of the freeform. Now I have to use materiallibs because I want to use some shader. But if I add a materiallib to my free from I get a ugly result from it. You can see the effect on this picture

[image: Link to image]

Where is my mistake?

Thanks for any answer or tip

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the texture is not active. Did you enable it in the material library?