# 'designide' must be recompiled when installing DWScript on Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dwscript

I'm running Delphi XE2 w/ update 3.

I've just checked out the read-only branch of DWScript from the svn repository. I try to install dwsLib.dpk from the DelphiXE2 folder but receive the following error:

```
[DCC Fatal Error] dwsLibRuntime.dpk(30): E2225 Never-build package 'designide' must be recompiled
```

I tried building dwsLibRuntime.dpk first, but I get an error about missing TdwsUnit component, so that doesn't work, either. I'm not having any luck finding contact info for the author, so am trying here.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact Eric directly

Comment: I'm finding highly suspicious what package named **runtime** depends on design-time `designide`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: DWScript doesn't target Delphi XE2.

Quote:

> DWScript lead platform is currently Delphi XE, compatibility with
>   Delphi 2009 & Delphi 2010 is maintained, but some features may be
>   restricted (RTTI f.i.).

You must fix the source code if you want it to work with Delphi XE2.

Comment: OK, but in the SVN repository they do provide XE2 dpk files and there is a blog post from the author that they are now supporting XE2 32- and 64-bit. [DWScript compatible with XE2](http://delphitools.info/2011/09/01/dwscript-compatible-with-xe2/)

Comment: The blog was posted on September 1st, 2011. As of now, you can find in the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/wiki/FAQ) (Updated Nov 17, 2011 ) another contradictory info: Delphi 2009 is the current minimum version. `Development happens on Delphi XE however, so SVN version may temporarily become incompatible with previous versions`.

Comment: [Eric Grange](http://stackoverflow.com/users/76349/eric-grange) is an SO member. I have made an attempt to bring your post to his attention [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9125269/744588). I wish you good luck.

Comment: Thank you, @menjaraz, I appreciate you forwarding that on.

Comment: XE2 is indeed not a platform I work on/use, so XE2 compatibility (like D2009 & D2010) is provided primarily by users. The differences should be limited, and whenever fixes are submitted, I commit them ASAP, but I don't have practical means to test them (beyond making sure they don't break the XE version, and I only have infrequent access to XE2).

Comment: Thanks, Eric. What it amounted to was fixing some paths to get the dwsLibRuntime to compile and then dropping and re-adding the three non-dws required dcps (designide, rtl, vcl) in dwsLib. I'm good to go now and looking forward to experimenting with DWScript.

Answer (score 1):

I.am using XE2 with the trunk code and it works fine. I loaded up each dpi (there are two) and built and installed the first. Then compile your code ensuring that you point to the source folders (there are at least three). Failing that I'll post you an innosetup exe that installs it into XE2 that I've made,